# undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass with partial validation of wizard gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, formwizard

I am trying to follow the guide for partial validation on object using the wizard gem, but I keep getting the error undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass, cant understand what is wrong, have tried to follow the step by step instructions.

The error in the log shows.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass:
app/models/property.rb:22:in `active_or_tenants?'
```

Here is my steps controller.

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :tenant, :confirmed 

  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @tenants = @property.tenants.new(params[:tenant_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    params[:property][:status] = step.to_s
    params[:property][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @property.update_attributes(params[:property])
    render_wizard @property
  end

  def create
    @property = current_user.properties.build(params[:property])
      logger.info @property.attributes
    if @property.save
        flash[:success] = "Tenant Added"
        redirect_to wizard_path(steps.second, :property_id => @property.id)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes, :property_id, :status
  belongs_to :user 

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :tenants 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenants, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :name,        :presence => true
  validates :address,     :presence => true
  validates :tenants,     :presence => true, :if => :active_or_tenants?

  def active?
    status == 'active'
  end

  def active_or_tenants?
    status.include?('tenants') || active?
  end
end
```

Let me know if you need any other parts added to the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which line comes from the error?

Comment: line 22 in property.rb NoMethodError - undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/property.rb:22:in `active_or_tenants?'

Comment: Oh! I see... Status is actually a column (attribute) of the Property class, right? If yes, then replace `status.include?('tenants') || active?` with `(status || '').include?('tenants') || active?`

Comment: Thats fixed it, could you explain the difference between the two please?

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna post an answer ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my comments:

The `status` is an attribute of your Property model. It can be `nil` which raises an error in certain cases:

```
undefined method include?' for nil:NilClass
```

It is actually trying to compare `nil` to `'tenants'` (String).

**To fix that**, you can use an empty string to be compared if `status` is `nil`,

```
# an example (you can try in your IRB console):
nil || "No value"
# => returns "No value"
```

in your case:

```
def active_or_tenants?
  status.to_s.include?('tenants') || active?
end
```

`nil.to_s` return an empty string. Which solves your problem ;)

---

Actually, the methods `to_s`, `to_i`, `to_f` etc. are often used to remove the possible `nil`:

```
# in ruby console:
2.3.3 :018 > nil.to_i
# => 0 
2.3.3 :019 > nil.to_f
# => 0.0 
2.3.3 :020 > nil.to_s
# => "" 
2.3.3 :021 > nil.to_a
# => []
```

Comment: I am following this guide 
goo.gl/mKDxey to partial validation of objects using the wizard gem, do you think this would still make the partial validation work?

Comment: Yes because it will return the same thing, The tutorial is not handling the possible nil value for the column "status"

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.3 you can use the [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537), which will simply return nil when your object is nil and it won't throw an error.

```
def active_or_tenants?
  status&.include?('tenants') || active?
end
```

Comment: the attribute `status` is not an array but a string.

Comment: Thanks [MrYoshiji](http://stackoverflow.com/users/976775/mryoshiji), I don't know how I missed that, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution to this, you might want to set a default state upon object creation,  preferable in the migration.

```
class AddStatusToProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :status, default: 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Following this you'll never have `nil` for your state